# NUnit: Could not load file or assembly nunit.core

Tags: c#, msbuild, nunit

I'm having some trouble with getting NUnit to work with MSBuild. I've
got http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ and the following build file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <Import Project="3rdparty\MSBuild.Community.Tasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

 <ItemGroup>
   <TestAssembly Include="net.purpletube.minla.test\bin\Debug\*.test.dll" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <PropertyGroup>
   <NUnit-ToolPath>3rdparty\NUnit\</NUnit-ToolPath>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="Tests">
   <NUnit Assemblies="@(TestAssembly)" ToolPath="$(NUnit-ToolPath)" />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 3rdparty\NUnit\nunit-console.exe
>   /nologo
>   net.purpletube.minla.test\bin\Debug\net.purpletube.minla.test.dll
>   ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage:
>   Single  Execution Runtime: Default 
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'nunit.core, Version=2.5.9.10348,
>   Culture=neu  tral,
>   PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

nunit.core is in 3rdparty\NUnit\lib and running nunit-console at the
command line on it's own is fine, but if I specify the test assembly I
get the error. The following article:

http://nimtug.org/blogs/damien-mcgivern/archive/2006/05/17/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-nunit-core.aspx

Suggests it may be a problem with my test assembly, but I can't see anything.

Has anyone else seen and solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Fusion Log Viewer,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx
It will show you which assemblies are being loaded, or failing to load, as well as the locations it is using to resolve those.

Once you figure out which file it actually fails on, it may provider an additional clue.